# Trying to Generate a variable number of coloured patches at random positions

Tags: netlogo

I would like to control the number of black patches that are generated(for example generate 10 black patches in random positions). Right now I am generating a random amount in random locations. I am using netlogo.

```
    ask patches 
  [
    set pcolor grey 
   ask patch random-pxcor random-pycor [set pcolor black]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `n-of`:

```
ask patches [set pcolor gray]

ask n-of 10 patches [set pcolor black]
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Not quite, it gives the error message "expected this(patches highlighted) to be a number, but got a patch agentset instead"